# Why universal elements is special case of universal arrow?

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading Mac Lane's Categories for the working mathematician, and it says "The notion 'universal element' is a special case of the notion 'universal arrow'. Indeed, if * is the set with only one point, then any element $e \in Hr$ can be regarded as an arrow $e \colon * \rightarrow Hr$ in Ens."

My questions are, 
why $e$ can be regarded that way?

What is Ens?

In the book, it says that Ens is the category of all sets and functions within a set $V$, but I can't get it. Can you give a more precise description of such a category?

Comment: $\mathbf{Ens}$ is basically just a "bigger" set theoretic universe, such that the things that are proper classes with respect to the book's usual discourse are sets in $\mathbf{Ens}$; Mac Lane doesn't really axiomatize it. A good way to think of it is that most of the book takes place inside a Grothendieck universe, and $\mathbf{Ens}$ is the larger set theoretic world that contains that universe.

Comment: I do not get it either :-) Your question, I mean. Is it about Ens or about universal elements? Should you perhaps change your title?